Swagger V3 Example Value displaying date in undesired format despite using pattern
I have a Spring Boot app with REST API, and in one of the request object, I declared a field which is supposed to hold a date in the format ddMMyyyyHHmmss:
@Schema(description = "[PT]Data da ultima alteração do registro\n[EN]Last update register", example = "06082024111924", pattern = "ddMMyyyyHHmmss", format = "string")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "ddMMyyyyHHmmss")
private Date lastUpdate;

In the Swagger UI, the example value of this field in the request body is always shown as below :
"lastUpdate": "2024-11-06T18:15:07.141Z",

How can I adjust?

You should follow convention, use your own date time pattern is not good idea. Then I don't go further to looking for what you want to archive. You should follow RFC3339 https://swagger.io/specification/v2/#data-types .
